# Can't interpret prediction with neural network use

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to use TensorFlow in python, to make some prediction with cryptocurrency data. The problem is that the output of the prediction is like a 0.1-0.9 number whereas the cryptocurrency data should be a 10000-10100 format, and I don't find a solution to convert the 0.* number to the real one.

I've try to create a ratio, with substrat max - min from predicted values, and max-min from tested data, and divide to have a ratio but when I multiply this ratio with prediction there is a big rate of error ( found a 14000 number instead of a 10000 one )

Here some code :

```
train_start = 0
train_end = int(np.floor(0.7*n))
test_start = train_end
test_end = n
data_train = data[np.arange(train_start, train_end), :]
data_test = data[np.arange(test_start, test_end), :]


Scale data:

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_train = scaler.fit_transform(data_train)
data_test = scaler.transform(data_test)

Build X and y:

X_train = data_train[:, 1:]
y_train = data_train[:, 0]
X_test = data_test[:, 1:]
y_test = data_test[:, 0]

.
.
.

n_data = 10
n_neurons_1 = 1024
n_neurons_2 = 512
n_neurons_3 = 256
n_neurons_4 = 128
n_target = 1
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.compat.v1.float32, shape=[None, n_data])
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype=tf.compat.v1.float32, shape=[None])

Hidden layer
..
Output layer (must be transposed)
..
Cost function
..
Optimizer
..

Make Session:

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

Run initializer:

sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())

Setup interactive plot:

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(y_test)
line2, = ax1.plot(y_test*0.5)
plt.show()


epochs = 10
batch_size = 256
for e in range(epochs):

# Shuffle training data
shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(y_train)))
X_train = X_train[shuffle_indices]
y_train = y_train[shuffle_indices]

# Minibatch training
for i in range(0, len(y_train) // batch_size):
    start = i * batch_size
    batch_x = X_train[start:start + batch_size]
    batch_y = y_train[start:start + batch_size]
    # Run optimizer with batch
    sess.run(opt, feed_dict={X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})

    # Show progress
    if np.mod(i, 5) == 0:
        # Prediction
        pred = sess.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_test})

        #This pred var is the output of the prediction
```

I persiste my result in a file and this is what its looks like :

2019-08-21 06-AM;15310.444858356934;0.50021994;

2019-08-21 12-PM;14287.717187390663;0.46680558;

2019-08-21 06-PM;14104.63871795706;0.46082407;

For example, the last prediction is 0,46 but when I try to convert it I found 14104 whereas it should be nearer a 10000 value

Does anyone have an idea how to convert those predictions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make use of [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) of `MinMaxScaler` to convert back the output you are getting in range of 0-1.

You have not given your model, but I believe you are making use of regression task with few dense layers. You will have to keep minimizing your loss. If you are using mean squared error, the larger the loss, more is the likelihood your output will be far away from the desired set of results.

Even after your loss is a small number and the result is coming good for train samples, but the prediction is bad for test dataset, you may have to consider increasing your train dataset so that more possibilities are covered. If that is not possible, consider reducing the number of neurons in your neural network so that it stops over-fitting.

You can do some postprocessing to restrict the output to some desired range.